# Is Asynchronous Programming possible with C or C++?

Tags: c++, c

Javascript facilitates asynchronous programming. Is Asynchronous programming using callbacks instead of uniflow, possible with C? (or C++)

PS: its evident that C# 5.0 has implemented it.

Edit:

What are the frameworks similar to nodejs in C and in C++?

Edit 2:
Asynchronous programming helps to scale users up without need of multithreading (which is important for large user applications) why may a callback based asynchronous approach for a regular application (with only 100s of users)?

Comment: Just take a look at Boost.Asio

Comment: Is there a framework like Node which uses C or C++?

Comment: With the new C++11 standard, there is [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async).

Comment: Pretty much anything the machine is capable of can be done in C, you just have to do it yourself. What do you think the JavaScript interpreter is written in?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker It's magic.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _asynchronous programming_? What do you want to achieve with _asynchronous programming_?

Comment: @nosid I am writing application in nodejs. Why is there no framework similar to node in C ?

Comment: @Program_Sauce Node is based on [libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv), a C library.  You might also be interested in [liblacewing](http://lacewing-project.org), a higher level library for asynchronous I/O.

Comment: As an aside, it's not like the advent of `async` in C# enabled asynchronous callbacks for the first time in the language.  Async calls can be performed on a single thread as well.

Comment: It's a widespread misconception, that asynchronous programming (as done by Node.js) has significant performance benefits over multi-threaded applications. If you have to handle less than 1M requests per second and less than 1M simultaneous connections per server, I strongly recommend using threads. In most cases, it significantly reduces the development efforts (_efficiency_), and it's easier to implement the requirements (_effectiveness_).

Comment: @nosid I disagree about there being a misconception. Async has a real benefit and you hardly need 1M concurrent connections to see it -- depending on what you're doing, in the 100s is close enough to start seeing large tangible results. Also, the spaghetti code problem of old-school async's dependency on callbacks (node.js, boost asio, etc.) has been solved efficiently in C# 5.0 -- try it out.

Comment: @CoryNelson: I have not seen any application in which it made a difference. But I'm really curious to see one - preferable running on a recent Linux kernel.

Comment: @nosid The purpose of async is specifically to reduce context switching and memory usage -- a kernel update might make thread scheduling more scalable or improve performance a little bit, but there are [inherent bottlenecks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law) with massive multi-threading that an update will never be able to resolve.

Comment: For a prime example, see lighttpd/nginx VS Apache.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion guys. Its educating. I think asynch programming may be elegant but for most application its way beyond over kill.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may need to manipulate threads, function pointers, functors, lambdas or you can use a dedicated library. Well, everything can be done in C++.

In your comments you are speaking about NodeJS. I guess you want is an asynchronous library for files, networks...
In this case you may take a look at `Boost.Asio` which ease the use of asynchronous programming in C++.

Here is quick example, partly from their documentation:

```
class server
{
public:
  server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
      const tcp::endpoint& endpoint)
    : acceptor_(io_service, endpoint)
  {
    do_accept();
  }

private:
  void do_accept()
  {
    acceptor_.async_accept(socket_,
        [this](boost::system::error_code ec)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            // Do your stuff here with the client socket when one arrive.
          }

          do_accept(); // Start another async call for another client.
        });
   // Your server can do some other stuff here without waiting for a client.
  }

  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};
```

This is a basic server that accepts some clients asynchronously. The function `tcp::acceptor::asyn_accept` will return imediatly and call later the callback when a client connect. In our case, this callback is a lambda function; a new feature from `C++11`.

Comment: Just in case anyone wants to copy/paste this code, watch out for the dangling pointer (`this`) when `server` is destructed before stopping the `io_service`.

Answer (score 3):

To implement callbacks the concepts needed are: function pointers (so that a routine knows what to callback); re-entrant programming style (a stack for automatic variables and no reliance on global or static vars that might get changed by other code); thread-safe code (e.g., for XP and above Microsoft's C Run Time (CRT) library is thread safe) so that routines like `printf` will function when entered from a call-back routine and a mainline routine; in some cases a method to serialize critical sections of code.

Also, in theory callbacks can be issued from other threads, so thread-safe code is necessary.

Anyway, notice that these descriptions are OS and language agnostic.  A programmer could write C code to implement these concepts, or the programmer could choose a different language.  It really depends on the application's requirements.

Comment: Most async libraries have some notion of schedulers which allow you to safely write everything as single-threaded code. In fact, if you are I/O bound this is often the best way to go!

Comment: However, if you wanted to you could still use threads and an async lib, they are NOT mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

of course it is. Think of the simple solution: you create a thread that accepts messages from some source (either internal or external), this thread dispatches the messages to a routine in a class or classes depending upon some defined data (maybe a string that says which class to call, or some ID that a plugin registers with the thread, etc).

When this routine completes processing it sends a message back to the main system that, dispatches it as it does with the rest of the system - a plugin doesn't have to be a server process, but can be a socket to a network client, for example.

Net result: async callbacks in both directions. Really simple to implement and no traditional threading issues either. This also has a benefit of running in a single thread, but there's no reason why you can't have a pool of threads that takes messages of the dispatch queue and processes them in parallel, thus scaling in a way that node.js doesn't.

Async programming doesn't really help to scale - in the case of node it just happens to work because node is designed for network programming where lots of small tasks are outweighed by the cost of the network traffic itself.